# Разделить строковый массив на 2 переменных

Tags: c#, массивы, строки, переменные

У меня есть массив:

```
string[] command = new string[] { "возьми", "эти", "таблетки", "*", "передавая", "таблетки", "пациенту" };
```

Нужно, чтобы в конце было 2 переменных:

```
var first = "возьми эти таблетки";
var second = "передавая таблетки пациенту";
```

"*" является разделителем между первой и второй частью. Он может находиться в любой части массива. Нужно чтобы код находил его сам.
Также и сами слова в массиве могут меняться.

Answer (score 4):

```
string[] command = new string[] { "возьми", "эти", "таблетки", "*", "передавая", "таблетки", "пациенту" };

var results = string.Join(" ", command).Split(new[] { " * " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
if (results.Length < 2)
{
    throw new ArgumentException(nameof(command));
}

var first = results[0];
var second = results[1];
```